# Reveal Extra Fields One at a Time by Clicking a Button (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I've recently started learning jQuery and I think I'm in love :)

Here's what I am trying to do...

Hide all **li input fields** except the first one. 
Have a button below the first input field that reveals the 2nd input field when clicked.
The button must move below the newly revealed input field.

When clicked again it must repeat the above until there aren't any more input fields.

I have tried a few ideas, the latest one is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nV9gE/). I know it's wrong, I am really stumped on this one, any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is my [temporary solution](http://prospurpharmacy.co.za/prescription-refills/#refillToggle) under "Show extra Refill Fields".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have simplified your markup just for readability
  See the working [example here](http://jsfiddle.net/nV9gE/36/)..

```
    <input type="text" /> 
    <input class="hide" /> 
    <input class="hide" /> 
    <input class="hide" /> 
    <input class="hide" /> 
<br /><button id="refill">Refill Another</button>
<style>
 .hide{
    display:none;
    visibility:collapse;
 }
 input{
    display:block;
    clear:both;
 }    
</style>
```

And a tiny bit of jQuery.. :)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#refill').click(function(){
        $('input').not(':visible').first().removeClass('hide');
        //thats all you need!
    });    
});
```

Comment: Thank you :) This worked really well using Contact Form 7 on Wordpress. Here it is on a test site: http://prospur.1013.co/prescriptions-and-orders/refill-prescriptions/#po

Comment: Saw it. :)  Glad I could help!

Answer (score 3):

http://jsfiddle.net/nV9gE/21/

```
<div id="container">
        <div id="content">

           <h2>Refill Your Prescription(s)</h2>
      <ul id="pofields">

        <li>
            <input name="prescription_1" type="text" size="40">
        </li>

      </ul>

            <input id="add" type="button" value="Refill Another Prescription">

        </div>
</div>
```

I changed the names of some of your id's and classes as you shouldn't use capital letters to start a id/class name

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $( "#add" ).click(function(){
            //get the name of the next input element
            var name = $('#pofields li').length + 1
            $('#pofields li:last').after('<li><input name="prescription_' + name + '" type="text" size="40"/></li>')
        });

});
```

Comment: This is a really nice script. It works perfectly in a HTML page, but I'm using Wordpress with Contact Form 7 so I can't figure out how to incorporate the Shortcode into you script. I was successful with a different method, will post in a sec.

Comment: @conqenator script did the job better, but yours is going to come in handy with plain HTML sites. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a container for input fields, so when you click on button you need just append another text field to this container. you can clone first text field, change its parameters and then append it to container.


`<div id="container">
    <input type="text" name="something[]" />
</div>
<input type="button" name="add" />
<script>
    $("input[name=add]").click(function(){
        $("#container").append('<input type="text" name="something[]" />');
    });
</script>`

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply :) I am going to play around with that idea now. Could you maybe give me a rough idea by editing this code: http://jsfiddle.net/nV9gE/

Comment: @Duane : these are wrong: "li#one.POadd" & switchClass(".hide", ".show", 1000) and the corrects are "li#one .POadd", switchClass("hide", "show", 1000)

Comment: Thanks for your input :) I found that @conqenator script worked better for my situation. http://prospur.1013.co/prescriptions-and-orders/refill-prescriptions/#po